# What transcription system from Japanese used ÿ?

Tags: spelling, typography, proper-noun, japanese

In a German map from the late 40's (my guess, judging from the nations and borders) of East Asia, the island of [Miyakojima](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miyako-jima) is transcribed Mÿako. What transcription system is this? I know the Japanese や used to be transcribed ‘ja’ (nowadays ‘ya’), and I know ‘ij’ ca been set as ÿ, but as Mi and -ya/-ja are different [morae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_(Japanese_prosody)), and different syllables, it looks a bit weird, or at least difficult to parse correctly. Was this ever part of a Japanese/German transcription system, or is it just something that this mapmaker came up with?

[image: Map showing Ishigaki and Miyakojima]

(suggested tags: `japanese-to-german` `transcription` `trema`)

Comment: Can you show us a *y* in the respective typeface? It may give a hint as to whether that’s an *ÿ* or *ĳ* we are dealing with.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft You are right, I found an 'y' now, and it looks completely different, so this is just a peculiarity of the font, as Uwe puts it below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is "ij", not "ÿ" ("y" with diaeresis). It's  just a peculiarity of the font used for this map that many letters connect to the following one (compare "i", "m", and "t" in "Iriomote"), so that "i" followed by "j" looks a bit like a dotted "y".

Comment: ... a peculiarity called a ligature (German: Ligatur).

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann "Ligature" in which sense? The [Wikipedia article on
ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature)
says "In hand writing, a ligature is made by joining two or more
characters in *atypical fashion* by merging their parts or by writing one above
or inside the other. While in printing, a ligature is a group of characters
that is *typeset as a unit*, and the characters do not have to be joined." ...

Comment: ... But for most letter connections in the sample image, neither of these holds.
The connection of "i" to "j" looks exactly like the connections of "i"
to "g", "l", or "o", or of "a" or "m" to "o", so it's not an *atypical*
connection in this typeface.
And it's highly unlikely that the typeface provides "chig" or "ilung"
as individual "sorts" to be *typeset as a unit*, even though those letters
are connected.